This is a rebus
Body must be at least 30 characters, so here it is: This is a rebus:


Could someone explain the downvotes?

Don’t take it personally: but here are a few possible reasons I see, 1) the answer is already stated in the question and flavor text making it seem like the puzzle is too trivial 2) the puzzle lacks the fun rebusy elements where one has to be imaginative to decipher a catchphrase (or word but that’s more challenging to make as clever imo) - it’s all too plainly obvious with highly cliche rebus tricks 3) it doesn’t seem like something that required tremendous effort to put together 4) a couple of the images phonetically speaking kind of stretch since they don’t fit nicely


the second image=‘eek’ is a little bit too tenuous a connection imo 6) it doesn’t seem to match the high quality that the other puzzles you posted possessed.


(Haven't voted) I think the trick itself is pretty fun - it's simple but it made me smile when I twigged what was happening. However, I reckon a lot of the criticism will fall on that last picture - it just doesn't sound like what it needs to. Sorry!

@PDT It is a quick one, not every puzzle has to be a deep complex one. I expected few views, maybe one or two upvotes, just an in between. I didn't expect this much downvotes. But looks like if someone starts to downvote, people will downvote more easily. It's interesting how things go :)

@Lezzup I don’t think there is anything wrong with a puzzle being ‘simple’ I.e possessing few steps but there is I think something wrong with it being trivial, it’s just that I (and presumably the downvoters) had high expectations that the underlying logic was highly imaginative and clever but then was disappointed when discovering the answer fell way short of that. (But that’s maybe because I have done a lot of dingbat sheets before and have so seen some devilishly brilliant rebuses).

Yes, it is...

 because each image represents a letter in the word REBUS! (Some are somewhat strained.)

 "Arr" (R) is what a pirate says.
 "Eek" (E, sort of) is what someone scared of a mouse says.
 The third image is a bee (B).
 The fourth image represents you (U).
 And the fifth is ash (S, sort of).

